# Finding a row in a datatable that is the closest to my parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable and I would like to find the row that has the closest value for TRK_Distance and return it.  I tried this and it throws an exception that it cannot find the column ABS(TRK_Distance - 1600) (1600 is my value that I am passing in for entry)

```
var tempRow = data.Select("*", "ABS(TRK_Distance - " + entry+ ")")[0];
```

How can I achieve this?  And is there a better way to go about it than how I'm doing it now?

Comment: Linq can't use ABS. You'll need to do it manually or do the query on your dbms.

Comment: Is there a way to get the closest value using linq?  i.e. can I formulate this differently and get the result I want?

Comment: Not that I know of. You'll most likely have to use a loop.

Comment: Is there someway that I can use the ideas listed @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723321/linq-to-get-closest-value and apply them to a datatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this with linq:

```
  var closest = data.Select().
    OrderBy(dr => Math.Abs((int)dr["TRK_Distance"] - 1600)).
    FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: that returns a double not a DataRow.

Comment: @PlTaylor, you're right.  I've edited my answer such that closest is a DataRow.

Comment: That works except for the conversion to int.  But that is my fault for not specifying that the 1600 was really 1600.0.  I ended up with data.Select().OrderBy(dr => Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(dr[parameter]) - entry)).ToList()[0]; for future reference.

Comment: If you know the type of dr[parameter] you can avoid some extra boxing overhead by casting it instead of using Convert.ToDouble.  i.e.

    (double)dr[parameter]  // I know dr[parameter] contains a double.

Comment: Instead of ToList()[0] you should just call First() or FirstOrDefault()