# Join two dictionaries by value diffs

Tags: c#, linq

I have these two dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<char, double> analyzed_symbols = new Dictionary<char, double>();
Dictionary<char, double> decode_symbols = new Dictionary<char, double>();
```

I need to create another dictionary that should have their keys as key and value, like this:

```
Dictionary<char, char> replace_symbols = new Dictionary<char, char>();
```

The condition to "join" them is that difference between values should be minimal, like this:

```
Math.Min(Math.Abs(analyzed_symbols[key] - decode_symbols[key]))
```

I guess I should use LINQ for this purpose but can't figure out how to write query properly.

Data Sample:

```
analyzed_symbols = [a, 173], [b, 1522], [z, 99]
decode_symbols = [в, 100], [д, 185], [e, 1622]
```

For these dicts output data should look like this:

```
replace_symbols = [z, в], [b, е], [a, д]
```

I've found [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723321/linq-to-get-closest-value) that is pretty close to what I need, but not exactly. Snowy asks there about one close value, but I need to do the same thing for two dictionaries.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy the helmet fits you 1:1. ( as if it was first designed on your pic :-)).

Comment: Added sample data to question.

Comment: Zip/Union are your options. I dont understand extacly waht you want.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov can you provide expected output for you sample data?

Comment: Added some output data. Hope now it's more descriptive.

Comment: How large are your dictionaries? What happens when two entries in `decode_symbols` are equally valid (e.g. either two entries have the same value, or there is another entry with the same absolute difference, but the opposite sign?)

Comment: No difference what sign it is, it should be absolute. I just need to find nearest values.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov: What happens if two values are equally valid in `decode_symbols` (e.g. `analyzed = [a,50], [b,60], [c,60]`, and `decode = [d,55], [e,45], [f,45]`)? And again, how large are your dictionaries? That is going to be important when designing the solution.

Comment: In my case it should be just `[b,e]` and `[c,f]` because I need to edit dictionary manually anyway. There are not more than 150 elements in each dictionary.

Comment: Size of two dictionaries is always the same? I mean `analyzed_symbols.Count == decode_symbols.Count`?

Comment: No, in most cases they won't be same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my take on it:

```
var analyzed_symbols = new Dictionary<char, double>(){ {'a', 173}, {'b', 1522}, {'z', 99} };
var decode_symbols = new Dictionary<char, double>(){ {'в', 100}, {'д', 185}, {'e', 1622} };

var q = from a in analyzed_symbols
        from d in decode_symbols
        let tmp = new { A = a.Key, D = d.Key, Value = Math.Abs(a.Value - d.Value) }
        group tmp by tmp.A into g
        select new
        {
            Key = g.Key,
            Value = g.OrderBy (x => x.Value).Select (x => x.D).First()
        };

var replace_symbols = q.ToDictionary (x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll try. I divided into several queries, because it's more readable that way.

```
//sorting values of the dictionaries to easily get closest
var analyzedSortedValues = analyzed_symbols.Values.OrderBy(k => k);
var decodeSortedValues = decode_symbols.Values.OrderBy(k => k);

//creating pairs of the closest values. Here I use iterator index i to skip
//some values that have been used already (is it correct?)
var t = analyzedSortedValues.Select((k, i) => new { a = k, d = decodeSortedValues.Skip(i).Any() ? decodeSortedValues.Skip(i).First() : -1 });

//printing results by getting appropriate keys from corresponding dictionaries       
foreach (var item in t)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}, {1}]", analyzed_symbols.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value == item.a).Key, decode_symbols.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value == item.d).Key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure how to do it via LINQ but here is the longhand version of what you want to do.

```
private static Dictionary<char, char> BuildReplacementDictionary(Dictionary<char, double> analyzedSymbols,
                                                                 Dictionary<char, double> decodeSymbols)
{
    Dictionary<char, char> replaceSymbols = new Dictionary<char, char>(analyzedSymbols.Count);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<char, double> analyzedKvp in analyzedSymbols)
    {
        double bestMatchValue = double.MaxValue;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<char, double> decodeKvp in decodeSymbols)
        {
            var testValue = Math.Abs(analyzedKvp.Value - decodeKvp.Value);
            if (testValue <= bestMatchValue)
            {
                bestMatchValue = testValue;
                replaceSymbols[analyzedKvp.Key] = decodeKvp.Key;
            }
        }
    }
    return replaceSymbols;
}
```

What it does is it goes through each element of the analyzed dictionary, test every element of the decoded dictionary, and if that match is the same or better than the previous match it found it will use the new value from the decoded dictionary.

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but I think your code add's value to replaceSymbols everytime it gets testValue smaller than bestMatchValue.

Comment: Yes, what you missed is it ***replaces*** not adds. So it just overwrites whatever the current value of `replaceSymbols[analyzedKvp.Value]` which is the exact behavior we want to happen if `testValue` is a lower number than `bestMatchValue`