# Closest distance between input time and list of DateTimes

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I have a question about how to find the closest time between a list of DateTimes and an input time.

In particular, I have:

```
List<DateTime> logTimes; // that contain all time read from a log file
int number = logTimes.Count; //array lenght

TimeSpan A = enteredDateFirst.TimeOfDay; //input time by user
```

Now, I would have the output to suggest to the user what is the closest time with respect to his input.

Comment: And what prevents you from *"have a solution"*? Any difficulty?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Get Closest Value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723321/linq-to-get-closest-value)

Comment: Maybe the word "Solution" is wrong...if you have a suggestion to implement a little code to resolve this problem.

Comment: @nonac: the question is unclear. The datetimes contain also the date mwhile the timespan is just the time. You want to find the datetime which `TimeOfDay` property is nearest to `A`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Duration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `TimeSpan` and LINQ:

```
DateTime nearestTime = logTimes
    .OrderBy(dt => (dt.TimeOfDay - enteredDateFirst.TimeOfDay).Duration())
    .First();
```

This returns the `DateTime` which `TimeOfDay` property is nearest to the given time. Of course this approach ignores the date portion. If you want to find the nearest `DateTime`:

```
DateTime nearestDateTime = logTimes
    .OrderBy(dt => (dt - enteredDateFirst).Duration())
    .First();
```