# find the highest value that is less than a given number in a sorted list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to find the find the highest value that is less than a given number to a specified number in a sorted list of integers.

I have the following code

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 2, 5, 7, 10 };
int number = 9;
```

In the above example the expected outcome is 7.
I do

```
int closestSmaller = list.Aggregate((x,y) => Math.Abs(x-number) < Math.Abs(y-number) ? x : y);
```

But it returns 10.
My list has hundreds of thousands of numbers. The above was just a sample.

Comment: You should be calling `Last`, which allows you to specify a condition, e.g. the last number that is less than or equal to another number.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ```Last``` was the first I tried. It works but as i said for lists of hundreds of thousands of items is slow as it traverses the entire list

Comment: If the list is sorted, you can use [Array.BinarySearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch) to get at the relevant location quickly.

Comment: I did read the bit about the size of the array but the significance didn't sink in. I was coming back to recommend `BinarySearch` but was beaten to it. I do second that motion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ to Get Closest Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723321/linq-to-get-closest-value)

Comment: PS: The closest number here *is* 10, not 7. Are you looking for closest below the value?

Comment: For 100K items this kind of search would be very slow though. If the data comes from a database, the availability of indexes, RAM and powerful CPUs would mean `SELECT MAX(num) from numbers where num <9` would be a lot faster. Even in memory, if the list is sorted the search can be a lot faster using binary search. If you need to perform a lot of such operations it may be better to first sort the list. Numeric libraries like Numpy or the equivalent Math.NET, ML.NET etc can use parallelization and vectorization to do this faster.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos smaller as in the title

Answer (score 5):

As the list is sorted, you can use [Array.BinarySearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch) to get at the relevant location quickly. A bit tricky to evaluate the return value in case you don't hit an element exactly.

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 2, 5, 7, 10 };
int number = 1;

var index = Array.BinarySearch(list.ToArray(), number);
if (index < 0)
{
    index = ~index - 1;
    if (index >= 0)
        Console.WriteLine(list[index]);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("less than all elements in the list");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[index]);
}
```

Comment: That return value behavior of BinarySearch is pretty unexpected "the negative number returned is the bitwise complement of the index of the first element that is larger than value".

Comment: @Ralf I don't think that it is _unexpected_. You're searching something and a negative value indicates that the item was not found. So far so expected. But if you try to insert the item to the sorted list it specifies the insertion position - you only need to toggle the bits. You get the insertion position for free.

Comment: You have [BinarySearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-7.0) on the `List<T>`. No need to convert to Array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But Im looking to get the closest (smaller) value. The above does not return the closest (smaller) value

Comment: @pantonis There would be no solution that fits that requirement. Starting at the received index from `BinarySearch` you can look backward until you've found an item smaller than expected or run out of values. You can write your own implementation of `BinarySearch` that does not return the index of the first element greater than that but the index of the first item that't exact or greater than the searched item. After that you can decrement index by 1 and get the index of the expected element - but in that case you implement your own binary search.

Comment: @pantonis what exactly do you mean by "closest (smaller)"? The highest value that is still < the given number?

Comment: @KlausGütter correct highest value that is still less than the given number. I edited the title to be more accurate as you suggested above

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = list.Where(x => x < number).LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: This assumes the list is ordered

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `question` ==> find the closest number (smaller) in a `sorted list`

Comment: The problem is that the question asks one thing but the code is trying to find a different thing. The closest is 10. That's what the code tries to find. The closest *before* the value is 7.